# Laravel 5.8: orWhere anulls the whereHas effect

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do a simple search function. For that, I implemented the following query:

```
Profile::whereHas('accounts', function ($query) use ($id) { 
        $query->where('user_id', $id); 
    })
    ->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->paginate(20);
```

- The `whereHas` selects the profiles that the user with `$id` has.
- Then, with the `where` we figure out if the search match with some *username* in the database.
- Finally, we paginate the results.

All right so far.

The problem comes when I add a `orWhere` like that:

```
Profile::whereHas('accounts', function ($query) use ($id) { 
        $query->where('user_id', $id); 
    })
    ->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('fullname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->paginate(20);
```

I want that the query analyses if the search matchs with the *username* and/or the *fullname*. When I add the `orWhere` works, but the `whereHas` doesn't do its work and the results are from all the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
Profile::whereHas('accounts', function ($query) use ($id) { 
    $query->where('user_id', $id); 
})
->where(function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('fullname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
})
->paginate(20);
```